# Is it possible to add an icon of our app in ActionBar when I already have a back button in there?

Tags: android, android-layout

The most left will be the back button (unless we're on the Main / base activity), and then I want to insert a logo of my app, then the app's title.

In my onCreate:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and in my onOptionItemSelected:

```
    case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
```

I've tried adding:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.actionbaricon);
```

under the code I've posted first. It works on my Main activity, where it has no back button (although the icon was placed on the middle of the action bar & erases my app title). But in activities where I have a back button, it only allows the back button (and the app title)

Answer (score 0):

First: Add the new icon on your menu.xml within values.  Then handle the menu on your activity on onOptionsItemSelected().